# Graph theory : Trees

Tags: graphs

I need to determine all the trees on 25 vertices for which there exists an integer m ≥ 2, such
that the degree of each vertex gives the same remainder when divided by m.

Can somebody help ?

Comment: Hi, it is not clear to me what the actual question is, so it would be nice of you to specify it a bit more. Are you looking for the total number (up to isomorphism) of such trees? Also, I assume that this is some kind of homework problem -- in that case, please also include what progress you have already made as expecting the users here to solve your homework for you is generally looked down upon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $G = (V, E)$ is a tree with 25 vertices such that there exist some constants $c \geq 0$ and $m \geq 2$ such that $\operatorname{deg} v \equiv_m c$ for all $v$. Note that we can equivalently write $\operatorname{deg} v = a_v m + c$ for some $a_v \geq 0$.

Since $G$ is connected by definition, we get that it must have 24 edges in total, giving us
$$ \sum_{v \in V} \operatorname{deg} v = 2 \cdot |E| = 48.$$
We can express this sum using the aforementioned decomposition of the degrees in $G$ to get
$$
\begin{align*}
 \sum_{v \in V} \operatorname{deg} v 
 &= \sum_{v \in V} a_v m + c \\
 &= c |V| + m \sum_{v \in V} a_v \\
 &= 48.
\end{align*}
$$
Due to the both terms in the rewritten sum being non-negative, we get that $c$ must be 1 if we are to find any solutions.
Hence we get that $m$ must divide $48 - c|V| = 23$, which implies $m = 23$ as we required $m \geq 2$.

At this point, we know that any such $G$ satisfying your conditions does so with $c = 1$ and $m = 23$.
By using our new formula again, we find that the sum of our $a_v$ must also equal 1 and therefore, $G$ must be isomorphic to a tree with 1 internal node and 24 leaves, which is also known as the [star graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_(graph_theory)) $S_{24}$.